# Meteor circular imports

Tags: javascript, meteor, javascript-import

I have two files that try to import objects from eachother. if I then try to access one of the objects it is undefined.

file1 -----------------
import { ob1 } from 'file2'

const test = obj1.foo;

### export const obj2 = {bar: 123};

file2 -----------------
import { ob2 } from 'file1'

const test2 = obj2.bar;

### export const obj1 = {foo: 123};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `export const obj2 = {bar: 123};` is not a declaration but a command. It needs to run in order to make `obj2` available in `file1`'s export object.

Your code is similar to this:

```
var file1 = {};
var file2 = {};

const test = file2.obj1.foo;  // file2 doesn't have an obj1 field yet!
file1.obj2 = {bar: 123};

const test2 = file1.obj2.bar;
file2.obj1 = {foo: 123};
```

Consider putting all code that accesses imported objects (eg. collections) into a `Meteor.startup` callback.
https://docs.meteor.com/api/core.html#Meteor-startup